# SharedFlow won't emit value to subscriber at fragment (collect)

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow, kotlin-sharedflow

I want to use `SharedFlow` instead of `StateFlow` because first one doesn't require initial value

**ViewModel**:

```
val photosPaginData = photoRepository.getPhotosPagingData() // Flow<PagingData<Photo>>
    .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly)
```

**Fragment**:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    viewModel.photosPaginData.collect { pagingData ->
        photosAdapter.submitData(pagingData) // no calls here...
    }
}
```

I'm only trying to use it for the first time so mb I don't fully understand how it works.

It works fine if I replace `shareIn` with `stateIn` and set `null` as initial value (third parameter) but then in `collect` callback I need to check if it's not `null` before submit `PagingData` to the adapter

**Updated**

It seems if values are emitted before SharedFlow was started being collected then new subscribers won't receive the latest value

So I need to change `shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly)` to

```
shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed())
```

or to

```
shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, replay = 1)
```

to make it work

But which one is better? I just need to keep the same single instance of `PagingData`

Comment: There is a `PagingData.empty()`, instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against using `SharingStarted.Eagerly`, as it will never cancel the upstream flow, even if the observing activity/fragment is not observing any more.

> Tip for Android apps! You can use WhileSubscribed(5000) most of the time to keep the upstream flow active for 5 seconds more after the disappearance of the last collector.

Taken from: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/things-to-know-about-flows-sharein-and-statein-operators-20e6ccb2bc74